# How to adjust pry colors

Tags: ruby, pry

**Edit:** The faded gray is only an issue with version 0.9.7.3 and before.  It has since been changed to a darker gray.

Pry has nice colorizing, but the value returned when an object is created or changed is a faded gray that I can barely see.

```
 u = User.new
 =>#<User...   <<<<<< This is what is barely readable.
```

I tried messing with values in .pryrc, but couldn't get this, or any other color for that matter, to change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pry uses CodeRay for coloring, so you can put the following in your .pryrc file:

```
CodeRay.scan("example", :ruby).term # just to load necessary files

TERM_TOKEN_COLORS = {
    :symbol => '1;31' # will make symbols bolded and light red on my terminal
}

module CodeRay
    module Encoders
        class Term < Encoder
            # override old colors
            TERM_TOKEN_COLORS.each_pair do |key, value|
                TOKEN_COLORS[key] = value
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You can see here all values that can be customized (not sure which one exactly is the one you mentioned, but shouldn't be hard to track down):
https://github.com/rubychan/coderay/blob/master/lib/coderay/encoders/terminal.rb

Comment: That did it. I replaced `:symbol => '1;31'` with `:comment => '34'` to get standard blue. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I've now fixed this in Pry, so from the next release on, no-one else should have this problem :). https://github.com/pry/pry/commit/c91975bb51424a951a0f39a6e7652cb7aaf26d17

Comment: Nice. But had to change `class Term < Encoder` to `class Terminal < Encoder` to get it to work.