# How to change color of pry prompt string

Tags: ruby, pry

I'm using different bash prompt string color in my server and local computer, so that I can easily be aware of where I am.

But when I use `pry` in server there is only white and black.
Is there a way to colorize prompt string of `pry`?

Answer (score 2):

As an easy way, you can just:

```
Pry.config.prompt_name = "\e[0;31m#{Rails.env} \e[0m" # 31 means red
Pry.config.prompt_name = "\e[0;32m#{Rails.env} \e[0m" # 32 means green
```

You will see something like:

```
[2] production (main)>
    ^ red or green
```

Answer (score 1):

There's this gem called [pry-theme](https://github.com/kyrylo/pry-theme). Have a look.

Install using `gem install pry-theme`

Comment: Thanks for info, but I couldn't find the way to change prompt string of pry by using the gem.

Comment: I found this stackoverflow post. Have a look if you want to tinker with pry. Hope it helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798795/how-to-adjust-pry-colors